# Override WorldGuard flag

Tags: java, bukkit

I am developing a plugin that allows players to PVP in a WorldGuard regions with a `PVP: deny` flag, but only when a certain condition is true.

I have already tried:
- Setting the `priority` to `HIGHEST`
- Setting `event.setCancelled(false)`

I am new to Bukkit programming, so I am not really familiar with the capabilities yet.

Question: Is it possible to temporarily set the WorldGuard bypass permission for the player attacker? How can I do this? I have tried, but didn't succeed.

Question 2: Is it possible to cancel the WorldGuard event that sends the "You can't PvP here!" messages?

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.HIGHEST)
public void onEntityDamageByEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    Player attacker = (Player) event.getDamager();

    if(!conditionIsTrue) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
    else {
        event.setCancelled(false);
    }
} // onEntityDamageByEntity
```

Thank you for taking time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I did some more research, since no helpfull answers were placed.

<strike>**Question 1:** Is it possible to temporarily set the WorldGuard bypass permission for the player attacker?</strike>

**Answer:** It is possible, but not recommended. It's easier to cancel the WorldGuard event.

**Question 2:** Is it possible to cancel the WorldGuard event that sends the "You can't PvP here!" messages?

**Answer:** Yes, cancelling the onDisallowedPVPEvent will stop preventing the PVP and messages.

**Code:**

```
@EventHandler
public void onDisallowPvpEvent(DisallowedPVPEvent event) {
    if(//condition) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Answer to question 1: Going off of what you said being new to Bukkit, I would say no, it is not possible. The only way to achieve this is to decompile WorldGuard, add an if statement on the part you wish to control, make this if statement rely on a global variable on the server, and then recompile & save. You would then edit this global variable inside of your plugin (Such as `PlayerMeta` or `FixedMetaDataValues`).

Answer to question 2: Once again, this would require you do decompile, edit, and recompile. Although this would be alot simpler due to the fact that all you will have to really do for this is delete the 
    `sender.sendMessage("You can't pvp here"); part of the code.`

P.S: You should check if there is a config file for this plugin, because if there is i'd say that it probably has a setting to turn off this PvP message

Comment: Reply to your edit: I didn't want to disable the messages.